# Terminal Equivalent of Finder Sort Order

Tags: terminal, finder, sort

One of the features I like about the Finder is that it sorts numbers "correctly", i.e - a file named "Episode 10" will come after "Episode 9" in a list, rather than after "Episode 1".

However, I haven't been able to find a way to replicate this ordering on the command line with any of the basic tools such as `ls`, `sort` and so-on, though I may have just missed or misunderstood an option.

Is it possible to mimic the Finder's alphabetic sort order to sort numbers by value when encountered? If so, is there a means of doing this that is cross-platform (even partially)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GNU `ls` has the rather useful `-v` option that will do exactly what you want. Unfortunately there's no similar option for OS X's BSD-based `ls`.

A quick solution is to do the following:

```
$ ls | sort -n -k1.5
```

That sorts the output starting at the 5th character of the first field.

The same question was asked at StackOverflow and there are a number of other possible solutions [listed there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323619/how-to-sort-files-numerically-from-linux-command-line) (some are Linux-specific though).

Comment: wow...I did not know that :)

Comment: Thanks for this! It's a shame there isn't something more generic I could use, but I may be able to use the `-k` option combined with a quick sampling of files to try and configure it automatically; unfortunately I'm not always working with consistent formats, but I'm trying to make it automatic =)

Comment: @Haravikk You can always install GNU Coreutils and use the `ls` from there - probably easier than trying to fiddle with various `sort` parameters! It's easily installable from all of the third-party UNIX software installers - pkgsrc, MacPorts, Homebrew.

Comment: The -k option is about fields, not columns. A field is separated by whitespace, and a different separator can be specified with -t. So `ls | sort -n -k 2 -t '_'` sorts a list with names like "prefix_12345" and "prefix_1234".